# allowing a generic method to access a value that varies depending on what type is passed without an object instance

Tags: c#, oop, generics

I'm working with several related generic methods, of which this is the simplest:

```
static T GetGCD<T>(T a, T b) where T ...
{
    T c;
    while (!b.Equals(a.GetAdditiveIdentity()))
    {
        c = b;
        b = a.EuclideanDivideBy(b).Remainder;
        a = c;
    }
    return a;
}
```

So T has to be constrained in such a way as to give the method a guarantee that GetAdditiveIdentity and EuclideanDivideBy will be present. The problem is that all the ways I can think of to do this require an object instance to call both of them with respect to, and I need to be able to access GetAdditiveIdentity without an object reference. This is because in some of the other places where I handle generics subject to the same constraints, there are no object instances on hand, and some of the classes that have to be supported are abstract, so I don't have the option to constrain T with new() and create a throwaway object for the sole purpose of getting at GetAdditiveIdentity.

The value GetAdditiveIdentity needs to return doesn't depend on an object instance, so even if I could get by with doing it that way, it seems conceptually wrong. On the other hand, it *does* depend on the runtime type of T. For example, if T is a Number or Integer object, it should return

```
new Integer(0);
```

while if it's a Polynomial object, it should return

```
new Polynomial(new List<Integer>());
```

This means I can't give all the classes that need to be supported a common base class with GetAdditiveIdentity as a static member, constrain T by the base class, and call GetAdditiveIdentity from the name of the constraint.

What I wish I could do is T.GetAdditiveIdentity()/static method overloading, which I've searched around enough to know isn't supported by the language, but when people have asked about it before, either their circumstances were just different enough from mine that the suggested alternatives didn't apply, or I don't understand the idea of them quite well enough to see how they apply.

Edit: here is one of the places where having to access GetAdditiveIdentity through an instance is more inconvenient:

```
static List<T> PolynomialMultiply<T>(List<T> coefficientsA,
    List<T> coefficientsB) where T : IArithmetic<T>
{
    List<T> output = new List<T>();
    T instance;
    if (coefficientsA.Count > 0)
        instance = coefficientsA[0];
    else if (coefficientsB.Count > 0)
        instance = coefficientsB[0];
    else
        return output;        
    for (int i = 0; i < coefficientsA.Count + coefficientsB.Count - 1; ++i)
        output.Add(instance.GetAdditiveIdentity());
    for (int i = 0; i < coefficientsA.Count; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < coefficientsB.Count; ++j)
            output[i + j] = output[i + 
                j].Plus(coefficientsA[i].Times(coefficientsB[j]));
    return output;
}
```

One or both of the List arguments may have no elements, so the first seven lines of the body are necessary just to find something to call GetAdditiveIdentity on. I suppose seven lines is not a big deal, but it seems like there must be a better way.

Comment: It seems like you'd have to use Reflection to get at a static member of the run-time type that `a` or `b` is, e.g. `a.GetType().GetMethod(...)`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Do you figure that's a good solution?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Oh, wait, but that still necessarily requires an object instance, right? The whole point of making it static was to be able to get by without an instance.

Comment: Are you suggesting that you would be calling that method, i.e. `GetGCD`,  and passing null arguments?

Comment: @jmcilhinney I think I could do typeof(T) rather than a.GetType().

Comment: @jmcilhinney No, but there are other methods where I use generics in a similar way that have no arguments. I didn't include code for one of those because it would have been more difficult to make it make sense in isolation.